# must declare a body because it is not marked abstract or extern? C#/ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a normal web form with code behind, in this code behind I can instantiate a couple of classes I have in the root folder, such as:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page

{
    Helper helper = new Helper();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        Initialise();
    }
}
```

And in the Helper class:

```
public class Helper
{
```

It's working fine but I now want to move my class files (Helper.cs for example) to the app_code folder but when I run the application I get error on

```
SharePoint sharePoint = new SharePoint();

public string id { get; set; }

must declare a body because it is not marked abstract or extern
```

What is causing this issue and how do I fix it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public string id { get; set; }
```

is an automatic property and these were added in C# v3.0 / .Net v3.5, so ensure you are targetting this version or higher in your project settings. If you wish to target an earlier version you'll need to use properties with a backing field.

Answer (score 0):

do you have TargetFramework = "3.5" for the project ? Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95683/net-property-generating-must-declare-a-body-because-it-is-not-marked-abstract-o).

Answer (score 0):

```
public string id { get; set;}
```

This line is the issue, and the question has been answered above, but I am adding an aswer with code to illustrate how to put in backing fields for those who are new to C#.
This an example of what the backing fields would look like, for `public string id { get; set; }`:

```
    private string p_id="";
    public string id {
        get {
            return p_id;
        }
        set {
            p_id = value;
        }
    }
```

Note the initialized private string `p_id` that holds the actual value for the public string `id`. Also note that `value` is defined by the compiler, and is cast as a string in this instance. If the property `id` was an `int` instead, value would be cast as an int (integer) instead of a string.